# How to reduce the time of calculations in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, performance, for-loop

I have to perform some calculations for almost 5000 items. I have used parallel for loop and the time taken for these calculations is almost 5 sec. I want to do it in below 1 sec. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.
The code is this

```
Dim AverageVal As New Double
Dim maxVal, minVal As New Double
Dim error_ As New Double
Dim delta As New List(Of Double)

With gOutputStresses_LC(0)

    Dim UniqueTagsList As List(Of Integer) = gOutputStresses_LC(0).stresses.Select(Function(c) c.Tag0D).Distinct.ToList

    Parallel.ForEach(UniqueTagsList, Sub(Uniq)
                 Dim tstresses As New List(Of clsMSHStress)

                 tstresses = .stresses.FindAll(Function(s) s.Tag0D = Uniq)
                 tstresses.Sort(Function(x, y) x.Sxx.CompareTo(y.Sxx))
                 tstresses.Reverse()
                 'maxVal = tstresses(0).Sxx
                 'minVal = tstresses.Last.Sxx

                 error_ = Math.Abs((tstresses(0).Sxx - tstresses.Last.Sxx) / (tstresses(0).Sxx + tstresses.Last.Sxx))

                 If error_ < 10 Then
                     AverageVal = tstresses.Sum(Function(s) s.Sxx) / tstresses.Count
                     .stresses.FindAll(Function(s) s.Tag0D = Uniq).ForEach(Sub(c) c.Sxx = AverageVal)
                 Else
                     AverageVal = 0
                     delta = New List(Of Double)
                     For k As Integer = 1 To tstresses.Count - 1
                          delta.Add(tstresses(k).Sxx - tstresses(k - 1).Sxx)
                     Next

                     Dim idx As Integer = delta.FindIndex(Function(c) c = delta.Max)
                     For g As Integer = 0 To idx - 1
                         AverageVal += tstresses(g).Sxx

                     Next
                     AverageVal = AverageVal / idx
                     For g As Integer = 0 To idx - 1
                         tstresses(g).Sxx = AverageVal
                     Next

                     AverageVal = 0
                     For g As Integer = idx To tstresses.Count - 1
                         AverageVal += tstresses(g).Sxx
                     Next
                     AverageVal = AverageVal / (tstresses.Count - idx)
                     For g As Integer = idx To tstresses.Count - 1
                         tstresses(g).Sxx = AverageVal
                     Next
                     For p As Integer = 0 To tstresses.Count - 1
                         ''.Stresses.Where(Function(s) s.Tag0D = tstresses(p).Tag0D And s.Tag2D = tstresses(p).Tag2D) = tstresses(p)
                         'Dim idx As Integer =
                         .stresses(.stresses.FindIndex(Function(s) s.Tag0D = tstresses(p).Tag0D And s.Tag2D = tstresses(p).Tag2D)) = tstresses(p)
                     Next
                 End If
              End Sub)
End With
```

The `UniqueTagsList` contains almost 5000 items.

Comment: You can show respect for those who might help you by formatting your code cleanly, so things are not indented way to right and past the scrolling border.

Comment: Let me fix this.

Comment: Looks like the outage got in your way, but it's fine now. Looking through the code, I can say the final `For p` loop is completely wasted code. Since you're using a `cls` type prefix we can assume reference objects, so the assignments in the earlier `For g` loops **already set the original objects in the `.stresses` array**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5000 items is *nothing* if the algorithm is done correctly. We can probably do this in less than a second without needing to go parallel at all. Given a modern commodity CPU clocked at a modest, say, 2 GHz, that's 2 billion clock cycles. Even better, you probably get [at least 3 instructions per tick](https://lemire.me/blog/2019/12/05/instructions-per-cycle-amd-versus-intel/). That's 6 billion total. Simple division means we can fit this in a single second on a single non-parallel core as long as we're spending less than 1.2 million instructions per item. In fact, memory latency is probably our limiting factor here, and parallel execution might not even fix that.

A significant savings potential from the original is this loop (and similar):

```vb
For p As Integer = 0 To tstresses.Count - 1
    ''.Stresses.Where(Function(s) s.Tag0D = tstresses(p).Tag0D And s.Tag2D = tstresses(p).Tag2D) = tstresses(p)
    'Dim idx As Integer =
    .stresses(.stresses.FindIndex(Function(s) s.Tag0D = tstresses(p).Tag0D And s.Tag2D = tstresses(p).Tag2D)) = tstresses(p)
Next
```

It seems to be trying to match up each `tstresses` item with the same item from the original `gOutputStresses_LC` array. But since it also appears we are working with reference types (the `cls` prefix is not typically used for `Structure`), we can know *these are already the same object*, and the lookups back into the original array are not needed. All this will ever do is waste a bunch of time setting each array element to the same value it already has.

There is similar code elsewhere running `FindIndex()` or `FindAll()` doing extra lookups back in an earlier array. This extra work is significant and *not needed*, converting something that would be close to O(n) (after the sort) to something that's instead O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Once we understand this, the simplification opens up other avenues for improvement as well. In short, the code below should be MUCH faster by avoiding the creation of extra needless Lists/arrays and by significantly reducing the number of passes through the data.

I need to add a disclaimer that I typed this directly into the reply window, and without the benefit of any sample data to test against. It's likely there's a bug or two you'll still need to work through, including a potential off-by-one error around the final `IdxAtMaxDelta` break, so be sure to test thoroughly.

```
Dim TagGroups = gOutputStresses_LC(0).stresses.GroupBy(Function(c) c.Tag0D)

For Each grp In TagGroups
    Dim sorted = grp.OrderByDesc(Function(i) i).ToList()
    Dim last = sorted(sorted.Count - 1)
    Dim error_ As Double = Math.Abs( (sorted(0).Sxx - last.Sxx) / 
                                     (sorted(0).Sxx + last.Sxx) )

    If error_ < 10.0 Then
        Dim AverageVal As Double = sorted.Sum(Function(s) s.Sxx) / sorted.Count
        For Each item In grp
           item.Sxx = AverageVal
        Next
    Else
        ' Only need 2 loops through the data and NO NESTED PASSES
        ' (original code used 4 base passes, of which 2 had nested passes)

        Dim Total As Double = 0.0
        Dim idx As Integer = 0
        Dim prior As clsMSHStress = sorted(0)

        Dim MaxDelta As Integer = 0.0
        Dim IdxAtMaxDelta As Integer = 1
        Dim TotalAtMaxDelta As Double = 0.0

        ' Loop 1
        For Each item In sorted.Skip(1)
            total += item.Sxx
            idx += 1
            Dim delta As Double = item.Vss - prior.Vss
            prior = s
            If delta > MaxDelta Then
               MaxDelta = delta
               MaxIdx = idx
               TotalAtMaxDelta = total
            End If
        Next

        Dim lowAverage As Double = TotalAtMaxDelta / IdxAtMaxDelta
        Dim highAverage As Double = (Total - TotalATMaxDelta) /
                                    (sorted.Count - IdxAtMaxDelta)

        ' Loop 2 (first half)
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For i = 0 To IdxAtMaxDelta
            sorted(i).Vss = lowAverage
        Next
        ' Loop 2 (second half)
        For i = i To sorted.Count - 1
            sorted(i).Vss = highAverage
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Excellent work !

Comment: @Joel Coenhoorn It is working perfectly.